# is it appropriate to use "yet"

Tags: word-choice

For background, here is the story (just example, not real):

I applied for a job but they want a person who don't smoke. In my resume I wrote as I don't smoke. They invited me for interview. 15 min before interview meeting I smoke a cigar. When I talk with HR manager, He felt that I smell cigar and he asked me a question that I didn't understand.

In that context, my question follows.

Okay, As you see I didn't understand what he is asking, So I want to ask him a question to understand what he is asking clearly.

So Can I ask him like:

> Are you asking that I smoke **yet** I wrote I don't smoke on my cv?

So "is it appropriate to use "yet" there or something else you can recommend in place of **yet**?

Comment: No, 'yet' is not appropriate, IMHO.  It's better to use "while" or "although".

Comment: I would say "Are you asking me if I smoke, although I said I don't in my CV?", or, more formal, "Are you asking me whether I smoke in spite of the fact that ...". To me it would be pretty clear what you were trying to say, though the whole phrase is not correctly built.

Comment: @Buckminster thank you. what about "Are you asking me that I smoke as though I don't smoke according to information on my cv? "

Comment: @Michael Well, I would place it as "Are you asking me **if** (or *whether* not *that*) I smoke **although** (or *though* not *as though*) according to **the** information **in** my CV I don't smoke? "

Comment: @Buckminster why not "as though" up to your sentence? I m confused.

Comment: @Michael "as though" has a different meaning: "seems/looks like"; consider the first verse of "Yesterday" by The Beatles: "Now it looks as though they're here to stay"

Comment: I'd use, "even though" instead of "although" as it conveys the difference more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of options. Here's one:
*"Are you asking that I smoke, **despite the fact that** I wrote I don't smoke on my CV?"*